# C++ Variable not being instantiated properly

Tags: c++

```
Sprite1 *test = new Sprite1(450, 450, "enemy.bmp", *screen);
    test->DrawJon();
    SDL_Delay(1000);
    test->MoveJon(20,20);
```

I am getting a runtime error on line #2. It says access violation at 0x0

Sprite1 is a class I have defined and DrawJon() and MoneJon() in the class. This syntax is ok with the compiler but fails in runtime.

Sprite1.cpp

```
#include "Sprite1.h"

Sprite1::Sprite1(int posX, int posY, std::string imagePath, SDL_Surface screen) :     PosX(posX), PosY(posY), ImagePath(imagePath), Screen(screen)
{
void DrawSprite1Jon( int x, int y, SDL_Surface *sprite, SDL_Surface *screen );
void DrawJon();
void MoveJon(int xDist, int yDist);
}

void Sprite1::DrawSprite1Jon( int x, int y, SDL_Surface *sprite, SDL_Surface *screen )
{
//Make a temporary rectangle to hold the offsets
SDL_Rect offset;

//Give the offsets to the rectangle
offset.x = x;
offset.y = y;

//Blit the surface
SDL_BlitSurface( sprite, NULL, screen, &offset );

SDL_UpdateRect(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0);
}

void Sprite1::DrawJon()
{
#pragma region Char to String Conversion

string ImagePath;
char * writable = new char[ImagePath.size() + 1];
copy(ImagePath.begin(), ImagePath.end(), writable);
writable[ImagePath.size()] = '\0';

#pragma endregion

temp = SDL_LoadBMP(writable);
sprite = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
SDL_FreeSurface(temp);

// free the string after using it
delete[] writable;

DrawSprite1Jon(PosX, PosY, sprite, screen);
}
```

Sprite1.h

```
#include <string>
#include <SDL.h>
#include "Functions.h"

using namespace std;

class Sprite1
{
private:
    int PosX;
    int PosY;
    int xDist;
    int yDist;
    string ImagePath;
    SDL_Surface Screen;
    SDL_Surface *temp, *sprite, *screen;

public:
    Sprite1(int PosX, int PosY, string ImagePath, SDL_Surface Screen );
    void DrawSprite1Jon( int x, int y, SDL_Surface *sprite, SDL_Surface *screen);
    void DrawJon();
    void MoveJon(int xDist, int yDist);
};
```

## EDIT:

upon further investigation, it is this line

```
DrawSprite1Jon(PosX, PosY, sprite, screen);
```

That is failing in the DrawJon()

Comment: You need to do some *debugging*.

Comment: Show a minimal implementation of ctor and DrawJon method that fails

Comment: By all means, the three "void" keywords should not be in Sprite1::Sprite1. Does this really compile for you? :O

Comment: In my sprite1::sprite1 ctor in my Sprite1.cpp? Yes it compiles

Comment: Are you passing a pointer or a copy of the screen in the constructor? The code is not consistent.

Comment: @boPersson Well can you show me how to make this consistent?

Comment: The first step here is to **simplify your code**. And the first step to do *that* is to remove all those unnecessary pointers.

Comment: Which ones are unnecessary? All?

Comment: @Jonathan - From the code it seems like you pass `screen` by value to the constructor, but store a pointer. In that case, you have saved a pointer to the parameter and not to the original value. When you later use the pointer, the parameter is long gone and an access violation is a possible result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some problems with my implementation but in the end I had to build in release mode rather than debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

*At least* this piece of your code is broken:

```
string ImagePath;
char * writable = new char[ImagePath.size() + 1];
copy(ImagePath.begin(), ImagePath.end(), writable);
writable[ImagePath.size()] = '\0';
```

You are creating local ImagePath variable, not using the class member variable. The local variable *shadows* the member variable. Remove the local variable (first line in above snippet).

Also, you can probably (I'm not very familiar with SDL) do the loading simply like this:

```
temp = SDL_LoadBMP(ImagePath.c_str());
```

Then, just guessing, but image loading might be failing, and that function returns NULL pointer. So check return value and then check the error (either there is some SDL error function you can call, or you need to check standard errno global variable.

Further suggestion: turn on compiler warnings (for gcc: -W -Wall) and learn to understand (copying the warning to google is a good start) and then fix the warnings. Most of the time they are real bugs (hence the warning!) and even when they are not, fixing the warning will make your code better.

Comment: I have done this and you are right. That was a small problem but does not solve my question.

Comment: @JonathanO Added two paragraphs about possible fix and about turning on compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

I is apparent that you've just began to program in C++, maybe you have a javascript background, therefore you've tried to put function declarations into the constructor. It is a wrong idea here. (`#pragma`'s usually have some explicit meaning, you also misuse them here. [see eg. `#pragma GCC poison`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html))

I see a lot of confusion in this code.

I suggest, you grab a [great quality beginner C++ book](http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/), before going ahead with this piece of code. At this point I see no reason trying to hammer-out something reasonable from this code.

Comment: I get error type name is not allowed if I do this. I did not vote down your post.

Comment: -1: The suggested code is completely broken. You have changed three unintended, but valid, function declarations into something completely meaningless.

Comment: Ok, I've removed my downvote after your edits. I suspect this still isn't what was intended, but I'll leave that for the OP to decide.

Comment: @JohnBartholomew: Thanks for pointing me out that I missed things, I did not see at first look that he put also types there.

Comment: Have you tried this in vs? It seems to not compile for me. Please post the whole files so I make sure we are looking at the same code.